# "Inventory" and cataloging of non-moveable goods in company

Tags: inventory, catalog

We are currently in the process of cataloging our furniture and equipment and would need a program to enter everything we find. Somehow similar to an inventory, BUT most inventory software I found needs to pre-specify a product, and than you can add it, tailored towards business selling things, and keeping track of their storages. But we'd like to add a range of different objects "on the fly", with customisable parameters (room, id number, short desc.)

We currently use a legacy excel list for this, but this is already a clutter, and we'd like to have something with a interface where multiple can log in, view and change things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should search for "fixed asset management software". One example is [SnipeIT](https://snipeitapp.com/), even though it's more geared to IT Assets, it does have plugins (IIRC) to manage other assets (furniture, vehicles)
It's an open source web app so you could deploy it yourself on a server / computer.